# join multiple tables and fetch the status based on first table id

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

AGENT DB TABLE

```
agent_id  agent_name company_name
--------  ----------  -----------
1         AAA           XXX
2         BBB           YYY
3         CCC           ZZZ
4         DDD           XYZ
```

DRIVER DB TABLE

```
agent_id  driver_id   driver_name last_viewed
--------  ----------  ----------- -----------
2         1           EEE           1
2         2           FFF           0
2         3           GGG           0
1         4           HHH           0
3         5           III           1
3         6           JJJ           1
```

I WANT THE OUTPUT LIKE THIS

```
Agent Details     Driver details

1, AAA,             1 Drivers (0 active | 1 idle)
Company name

2, BBB,             3 Drivers (1 active | 2 idle)
Company name

3, CCC,             2 Drivers (2 active | 0 idle)
Company name
```

I have tried this below query

```
$sql="SELECT a.*,d.*, COUNT(d.driver_id) AS drivers_count FROM ta_agent a JOIN ta_drivers d USING(agent_id) GROUP BY a.agent_id";
```

I want to show active and idle status of the driver based on `last_viewed` column. For example  agent_id 2 have three drivers (1,2,3) and those 3 drivers have 1,0,0 in their last_viewed column. So, i want to show the output like this 1 active and 2 idle...

[image]

Comment: you should mention the table details pls

Comment: format your output pls with field name

Comment: do you want like this format `1, AAA,xxx, 1 HHH 0 `

Comment: i want the format like this `1, ABC, XYZ company    2 Drivers (1 active, 0 idle)`. i have updated my recent result. now,i want to add the active, idle status based on last_viewed column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,.

```
select a.agent_id, a.agent_name, a.company_name, ifnull(cnt_all,0) total_drivers,ifnull(cnt_active,0) active_drivers, ifnull(cnt_idle,0) idle_drivers
from agent a left join (select agent_id, count(*) cnt_all
                   from driver
                   group by agent_id) cnt on a.agent_id=cnt.agent_id

left join (select agent_id, count(*) cnt_idle
                   from driver
                   where last_viewed=0
                   group by agent_id) idle on a.agent_id=idle.agent_id

left join (select agent_id, count(*) cnt_active
                   from driver
                   where last_viewed=1
                   group by agent_id) active on a.agent_id=active.agent_id
```

here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5058f/6)

Comment: can you split the number of drivers, active and idle status separately

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking at ?

```
select 
concat(
  a.agent_id,' ',a.agent_name,' ',a.company_name
) as `Agent Details`,
concat(
 COUNT(d.driver_id),' Drivers (',
 ' Active ',sum(d.last_viewed = 1) 
 ,' | ',sum(d.last_viewed = 0 ),' idle ) '
)as `Driver details`

FROM AGENT a
LEFT JOIN DRIVER d USING(agent_id)
GROUP BY a.agent_id
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53e77/3)**

**UODATE** :
from last comment

> I don't want Driver Details -> 1 Drivers ( Active 0 | 1 idle ) I want
>   Number of Drivers -> 1 Drivers, Active -> 0, Idle -> 1

```
select 
concat(
  a.agent_id,' ',a.agent_name,' ',a.company_name
) as `Agent Details`,

concat ( COUNT(d.driver_id),' ',' Drivers')  as `Number of Drivers`,
sum(d.last_viewed = 1) as `Active`,        
sum(d.last_viewed = 0) as `Idle`
FROM AGENT a
LEFT JOIN DRIVER d USING(agent_id)
GROUP BY a.agent_id
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53e77/6

Comment: can you split the number of drivers, active and idle status separately

Comment: I did not get can u provide a view how it should look like.

Comment: I don't want `Driver Details -> 1 Drivers ( Active 0 | 1 idle )` I want `Number of Drivers -> 1 Drivers, Active -> 0, Idle -> 1`